# Comparing two Data Frames and getting differences

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to compare two Data Frames and print out my differences in a selective way. Here is what I want to accomplish in pictures:

Dataframe 1

[image: Dataframe 1]

Dataframe 2

[image: Dataframe 2]

Desired Output - Dataframe 3

[image: Desired Output - Dataframe 3]

What I have tried so far?

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_excel("01.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("02.xlsx")

def diff_pd(df1, df2):
    """Identify differences between two pandas DataFrames"""
    assert (df1.columns == df2.columns).all(), \
        "DataFrame column names are different"
    if any(df1.dtypes != df2.dtypes):
       "Data Types are different, trying to convert"
        df2 = df2.astype(df1.dtypes)
    if df1.equals(df2):
        return None
    else:        # need to account for np.nan != np.nan returning True
        diff_mask = (df1 != df2) & ~(df1.isnull() & df2.isnull())
        ne_stacked = diff_mask.stack()
        changed = ne_stacked[ne_stacked]
        changed.index.names = ['id', 'Naziv usluge']
        difference_locations = np.where(diff_mask)
       changed_from = df1.values[difference_locations]
        changed_to = df2.values[difference_locations]
    return pd.DataFrame({'Service Previous': changed_from, 'Service Current': changed_to},
                            index=changed.index)

df3 = diff_pd(df1, df2)

df3 = df3.fillna(0)
df3 = df3.reset_index()

print(df3)
```

To be fair i found that code on another thread, but it does get job done, but I still have some issues.

1. My dataframes are not equal, what do I do?
2. I don't fully understand the code I provided.

Thank you!

Comment: welcome to SO. Instead of using an image - simply copy your table (text) to this question using the 'Code Sample' note the {} in the frame.

Answer (score 0):

How about something easier to start with ...

Try this

```
import pandas as pd

data1={'Name':['Tom','Bob','Mary'],'Age':[20,30,40],'Pay':[10,10,20]}
data2={'Name':['Tom','Bob','Mary'],'Age':[40,30,20]}

df1=pd.DataFrame.from_records(data1)
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_records(data2)



# Checking Columns

for col in df1.columns:
    if col not in df2.columns:
        print(f"DF2 Missing Col {col}")

# Check Col Values 
for col in df1.columns:
    if col in df2.columns:
        # Ok we have the same column
        if list(df1[col]) == list(df2[col]):
            print(f"Columns {col} are the same")
        else:
            print(f"Columns {col} have differences")
```

It should output

```
DF2 Missing Col Pay
Columns Age have differences
Columns Name are the same
```

Python3.7 needed or change the f-string formatting.

Comment: Thanks. I still have a challenge what happens if number of rows are not equal in my data frames. I had an idea of merging and later, splitting them. Would that work?

I would merge them on "Customer number", "Customer name", "LocationID".

Comment: OK .... 

Then

```python
# Set Index to Name
df1.set_index(['Name'],inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['Name'],inplace=True)
# Now compute difference. 
# NaN indicates there is a missing data.... 
# Positive or Negative shows differences in data
# 0 indicates the record is the same
df2 - df1
```

Will show you the differences using Name as the "common"/key fields